# How to round circle inside UV

Tags: uv

[image: Summary]

I don't really know how to explain it, but the image is self-explanatory. Feel free to ask for more details if needed

Comment: Just scale it on X axis (select all UV, press S X, adjust with mouse and confirm with left click). G for grabbing in position.

Comment: Did the circle unwrap as an oval if so you may want to reset the scale of the object you are working on? I'm guessing your base object which looks like a scaled sphere you may have forgotten to reset the scale before you continued modelling in edit mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Check your view axis, you need to look at the face you need to unwrap. Maybe change to ortho to go 100%. Select the faces for the eyes, go to UV or press U for unwrap methods, select Project from view and check the scale to bounds.

Comment: Thanks a LOT! Worked perfectly, you are a hero